# How to use MUI styled components for selectors?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Here I am trying to convert the styles I have written in the CSS file to MUI-styled components. But I am facing challenges in that

**CSS**

```
.depth-0 + .depth-1 {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.depth-1 + .depth-0 {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.depth-1:last-child {
  box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 3px -3px rgb(50 50 50 / 75%);
}

.depth-1 + .depth-2 {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.depth-2 + .depth-1 {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.depth-2 + .depth-0 {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.depth-2:last-child {
  box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 3px -3px rgb(50 50 50 / 75%);
}

.depth-2 + .depth-3 {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.depth-3 + .depth-2 {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.depth-3 + .depth-1 {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.depth-3 + .depth-0 {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.depth-3:last-child {
  box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 3px -3px rgb(50 50 50 / 75%);
}
```

**MUI Styled**

```
const StyledContainer = styled('div')(() => ({
  '& .depth-0 + & .depth-1': {
      backgroundColor: 'pink !important'
  }
}))
```

The above code is not working. Could please guide me on how to covert the above CSS code in MUI styled?

Just for tries, I have added the `backgroundColor` in MUI styled.

Here is the working demo link for that - https://codesandbox.io/s/tanstack-table-expansion-pagination-9nuzit?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You should create styled-component with `css` settings as class as,

```
export const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  .depth-0 + .depth-1 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  }

  .depth-1 + .depth-0 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  }
  .depth-1:last-child {
    box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 3px -3px rgb(50 50 50 / 75%);
  }

  .depth-1 + .depth-2 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  }

  .depth-2 + .depth-1 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  }

  .depth-2 + .depth-0 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  }
  .depth-2:last-child {
    box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 3px -3px rgb(50 50 50 / 75%);
  }

  .depth-2 + .depth-3 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  }

  .depth-3 + .depth-2 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  }

  .depth-3 + .depth-1 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  }

  .depth-3 + .depth-0 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px -3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  }
  .depth-3:last-child {
    box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 3px -3px rgb(50 50 50 / 75%);
  }

  ///other css setting here that will apply on StyledContainer component.
`;
```

You can use component as,

....

Answer (score 1):

Try preceding the line with a single &,

```
const StyledContainer = styled('div')(() => ({
  '& .depth-0 + .depth-1': {
      backgroundColor: 'pink !important'
  }
}))
```

Also, for last-child and first-child selectors, use first-of-type and last-of-type

```
const StyledContainer = styled('div')(() => ({
      '& .depth-2:last-of-type': {
          backgroundColor: 'pink !important'
      },

      '& .depth-0:first-of-type': {
          backgroundColor: 'pink !important'
      }
    }))
```